# How to configure a plugin to apear on joomla 2.5 front end

Tags: web-applications, plugins, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have downloaded a social media plugin from this site http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/social-marketing-seo/floating-multi-share

I have enabled it and am not seeing it from the front end, and generally how do i configure plugins to appear on the front end

Comment: plugins do not appear, but are triggered for certain events. for example "before display content". some will be triggered only for articles, not for categories, for example. so the question is, what is on your front end?

Comment: Front-end is the site part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [make sure you understand what a plugin is.](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29)

Some extensions ship with a combination of a module - plugin - component.

Second, visually you can see a Module or a Component. To see a module you need to enable it and to decide on which template position it will appear.

If it's a component, you will most likely link it from the Menu, creating a new menu item.

Hope this helps.